# How do I get an ipa file in Xcode 15

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode15

On Xcode versions, before Xcode 15 we have an option Export

Export which I then saved a copy and uploaded to the app store with Transporter

This has vanished, I need to get a copy of the IPA before uploading because it is my company's policy for various reasons.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the option hidden away

If you select custom on the first screen you get back to the old flow.

[image]